# .htaccess regex should grab at least one character also grabs for zero characters

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have a rewrite rule where I want to redirect everything after the domain to a page.

So https://example.com/blahblah should redirect to https://example.com/page.php?id=blahblah

This part works but it also redirects https://example.com to https://example.com/page.php?id=

My rewrite rule is this: it should only grab one or more characters no empty characters

`RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)?$ page.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA]`

how do I exclude zero characters from it?

I've tried
`RewriteRule ^\/([a-z0-9-]+)?$ page.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA]`
and
`RewriteRule ^{HTTP_HOST}([a-z0-9-]+)?$ page.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA]`
with and without the slashes but both then fail to redirect anything.

Edit: this acts the same on both my website and in .htaccess testers.

Edit2: Trying `RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]{4})?$ page.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA]` does the same, it redirects if it's exactly 4 characters or if there's none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)$ https://example.com/page.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

The question mark `?` indicates zero or one occurrences of the preceding element. So in your case the homepage will be included in the `RewriteRule` and it shouldn’t.